# Avalance diode -looking symbols with two triangles in the case of backpressure pump?

Tags: pressure

I cannot understand the symbols [image] where you have some q terms, some arrows and white triangles. It is related to managed pressure drilling (MPD) of the system

[image]

where the system is different to conventional drilling in the respect that now we manage the pressure in certain drilling window. I think that is the reason why we need extra support system called *annulus* with support pump. I think the production is in the drillstring.

Yet **what is the purpose of triangles in the pictures? Are they like [avalance diodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_diode) so acting as blocks unless very massive pressure in which case they allow everything through?**

Comment: I think I answered by question but I found the solution from electronics instead of drilling, hope someone can verify the ideas :)

Comment: They appear to be gate valves.  See https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/ValveTypesSelection#Summary_Tables but I certainly can't help you with *why* they are there.

Comment: @floris yes I might be wrong, I erased my answer until I am more certain

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question, e.g. because of obvious analogue between hydrodynamics and electronic circuits?

Comment: @Qmechanic just create a label `petroleum-engineering`: mix of chemistry, mechaniscs, simple arithmetics and physics. I think it is better to use labels to differentiate first this kind of questions. I cannot due it yet because less than 1k points.

Comment: Tags are a separate issue.

Comment: It's off topic here, but I don't expect it to be on topic at [electronics.SE] either because it doesn't appear to be about an electronic device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a gate valve, as seen here:

[image]

Source: http://www.roymech.co.uk/Useful_Tables/Drawing/Flow_sheets.html